# Multiple copies of stylesheets stored in memory (leak)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, memory-leaks, less

I noticed that there are memory leaks in our application. I have been using Firefox's about:memory page to try and troubleshoot the problem. I noticed that there are multiple copies of our stylesheets (.less) e.g.:

```
230.01 MB (18.89%) -- string(length=415887, copies=230, "/**/n * Applies styles for users in high contrast mode. Note that this only applies/n * to Microsoft browsers. Chrome can be included by checking for the `html[hc]`/n * attribute, however Chrome handles high contrast differently./n * @param target Which kind of high contrast setting to target. Defaults to `active`, can be/n *    `white-on-black` or `black-on-white`./n *//n/* Theme for the ripple elements.*//n/* stylelint-disable material/no-prefixes *//n/* stylelint-enable *//n.mat-badge-content {/n  font-weight: 600;/n  font-size: 12px;/n  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }/n.mat-badge-small .mat-badge-content {/n  font-size: 6px; }/n.mat-badge-large .mat-badge-content {/n  font-size: 24px; }/n.mat-h1, .mat-headline, .mat-typography h1 {/n  font: 400 24px/32px Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;/n  margin: 0 0 16px; }/n.mat-h2, .mat-title, .mat-typography h2 {/n  font: 500 20px/32px Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;/n  margin: 0 0 16px; }/n.mat-h3, .mat-subheading-2, .mat-typography " (truncated))
│  │  │  │    ├──230.00 MB (18.89%) ── malloc-heap/two-byte
│  │  │  │    └────0.01 MB (00.00%) ── gc-heap/two-byte
```

After ~15 hours the stylesheets take up 1GB of memory and the number of copies keep increasing! I just don't understand why this happens?

The page component looks like this:

```html
    <div *ngIf="!showSSNInput">
        <div class="msg msg-error" *ngIf="showNotFoundError">text</div>
        <iframe id="nemid_iframe" name="nemid_iframe" ontouchstart="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:300px;height:460px;border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="showSSNInput">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4>text</h4>
            <div class="field-input">
                <input class="cpr-input" type="text" required name="cpr" [(ngModel)]="ssnInput" (ngModelChange)="cleanSsnMask()"
                       (keyup.enter)="loginWithSsn()" [class.missing-input]="ssnInput == null || ssnInput.length === 0" [textMask]="{mask: CPRmask}" />
                <span class="floating-label">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="field-input">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-login" (click)="loginWithSsn()" [disabled]="cleanSsn == null || cleanSsn.length != 10 || loading"
                        [class.loading]="loading" type="button">
                    <span>text</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="msg msg-error" *ngIf="showSSNError">text</div>
            <div class="msg msg-error" *ngIf="showNotFoundError">text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="msg msg-error" *ngIf="showError">
        <b>text {{errorCode}}</b>
        text
    </div>
```

```less
    @import "../../../../../assets/styles/app/functions.less";

    .btn-login {
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        padding: 12px 20px 11px;
    }

    .cpr-input{
        width: 200px; 
        .extraSmallDevice({
            width: 100%;
        })
    }

    .msg {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

webpack.config.js:

```json
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', options: { useCache: true } },
        { test: /.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'raw-loader!less-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    ),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/iisnode.yml', to: 'iisnode.yml' },
        { from: 'src/web.config', to: 'web.config' }
    ])
  ]
}
```

Angular version: 7.0.1

Let me know if there's more information needed to figure it out.

Comment: `After ~15 hours` do you mean after 15 hours of the app running in browser without any user interaction? can you share your webpack config - how you build it? How do you serve the page?

Comment: @Mykybo I initially clicked around a bit and then just left the window open with no interaction for 15 hours. I'll add the Webpack config to the question. It's launched through .net core which runs ng serve in the development environment.

Comment: The problem seems to be due to a third party iframe. I solved it by simply removing the iframe from DOM after x minutes.